# Ambiguous occurrence Show in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a problem to "show" a result of a simple function in Haskell.
The "assignment" is: returns a sequence equal to that of the past in which each value "War" is replaced with a value "Star" and viceversa:

```
data El = Star | War

class Show a where
    show :: a -> String

instance Show El where
    show Star = "Star"
    show War = "War"

swapSeq :: [El] -> [El]
    swapSeq [] = []
    swapSeq (Star:xs) = Star : swapSeq xs
    swapSeq (War:xs) = War : swapSeq xs
```

Thanks to everyone for your help!

Comment: You write: *I have a problem [...]* What *is* the problem? Edit your answer and explain *where* you've hit a wall. Do you get an error? If so, describe it. It looks like you're trying to redefine the `Show` type class. That's probably not what you want to do. By the way, in this case, you could simply stick `deriving Show` after your data declaration instead of making `El` an instance of `Show` with `instance`.

Comment: For one thing your indention is all wrong in `swapSeq`, but did you perhaps want `swapSeq (Star xs) = War : swapSeq xs`, and similarly on the next line?  We really don't know what your problem is, and no one wants to do your homework for you.

Comment: what is the "sequence ... of the past" and how does it look like?

Comment: @bheklilr I'll leave my answer, because it's already written and the OP is a new user, but you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `class` keyword is used for defining a brand new type class. You don't want to define `Show`; it's already defined in the Prelude. Therefore, you should get rid of

```hs
class Show a where
    show :: a -> String
```

Another problem is the messed up indentation in the definition of `swapSeq`. Fix it or you will get a `parse error on input ‘=’` error.

Finally, you apparently don't want `show` to convert your `El` values to any fancy string; you just want to use the name of the value. In that case, you can simply let Haskell derive `Show` automatically for your datatype, by sticking `deriving Show` after your data declaration; that's easier than making `El` an instance of `Show` with the `instance` keyword.

```hs
data El = Star | War deriving Show

swapSeq :: [El] -> [El]
swapSeq []        = []
swapSeq (Star:xs) = Star : swapSeq xs
swapSeq (War:xs)  = War  : swapSeq xs
```